# AES Encryption in Python is different form iOS

Tags: python, ios, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in IOS and then send it to a TCP server. Python version of code and iOS versions are shown below. Please see outputs of the both versions. They look quite similar but the lengths are different and I do not know the reason. Can anybody check it , what could be the reason?

Please note that  PADDING in Python script should be discarded , as I gave a text length of 16 already.

PYTHON Code:

```
     #!/usr/bin/env python

     from Crypto.Cipher import AES
     import base64
     import os

     # the block size for the cipher object; must be 16, 24, or 32 for AES
     BLOCK_SIZE = 16

     PADDING = '{'

     # one-liner to sufficiently pad the text to be encrypted
     pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

     # one-liners to encrypt/encode and decrypt/decode a string
     # encrypt with AES, encode with base64
     EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
     DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)


     secret = "1234567890123456" 

     # create a cipher object using the random secret
     cipher = AES.new(secret)

     encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, 'password12345678')
     print 'Encrypted string:', encoded

     decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
     print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
```

OUTPUT:

Encrypted string: 57AayWF4jKYx7KzGkwudIBZUsn1ULOC0C4c5YF3xeI8=

Decrypted string: password12345678

```
NSString *forKey=@"1234567890123456";
NSString *mystr =@"password12345678";
const char *utfString = [mystr UTF8String];
NSData *aData=[NSData dataWithBytes: utfString length: strlen(utfString)];
aData=[mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data;//=[aData AES128EncryptWithKey:forKey];
data=[aData AES128EncryptWithKey:forKey];

NSString *base64 = [data base64EncodedString];

aData=[data AES128DecryptWithKey:forKey];
mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"AES data : %@  \n %@",mystr,base64 );
```

OUTPUT:

AES data : password12345678
 57AayWF4jKYx7KzGkwudIKNlwA+HErrmiy1Z0szzZds=

Comment: You can only ignore the padding if you're using [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). I hope you're not using ECB mode.

Comment: I have not set the mode in Python , I believe it is using the default value.

Comment: @sarnold ECB mode requires padding as well, the IV should not be set in ECB mode or set to all zero's (if the platform requires an IV), but padding is certainly required. Or is that specific to the Python/iOS platform?

Comment: @owlstead: in the specific case of 16 bytes of input data, you can use ECB mode without padding. You shouldn't use ECB mode, of course, but you can certainly encrypt 16 bytes of data without any padding.

Comment: @sarnold but this is no different in ECB mode or CBC mode, if you know the length in advance and you have blocksize * N bytes, then you don't have to pad. As ECB mode is only suitable for randomized data (mostly keys) it is somewhat more likely that padding is not the default, hence my question about the platform/runtime.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. What code are you using for the NSDATA category that implements: AES128EncryptWithKey ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK , here it is. Thanks sarnold for the clue :)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

    # the block size for the cipher object; must be 16, 24, or 32 for AES
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    secret = "1234567890123456" #os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

    # create a cipher object using the random secret
    cipher = AES.new(secret,mode)

    # encode a string
    #tx=cipher.encrypt('1234567890123456')
    #print base64.b64encode(tx)

    myData='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    #encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, myData)
    encoded = cipher.encrypt(myData)
    print 'Encrypted string:', base64.b64encode(encoded)
    mode = AES.MODE_ECB
    cipher=AES.new(secret,mode)
    decoded = cipher.decrypt(encoded)
    print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
```

**Python OUTPUT:**

Encrypted string: C9pEG6g8ge76xt2q9XLbpw==

Decrypted string: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

> *Changed AES CCOptions to kCCOptionECBMode in iOS. *

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,keyPtr, CCKeySizeAES128, NULL,[self bytes], dataLength,  buffer, bufferSize,  &numBytesEncrypted);
```

And now output is:

**iOS Output:**

AES data : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 C9pEG6g8ge76xt2q9XLbpw==

Comment: Nice job :) Though I think you shouldn't have selected "community wiki" -- there's nothing wrong with answering your own questions, and this answer is definitely better than many. You ought to get reputation from it. ;)

Comment: Wiki status removed. Community wiki is useful when you want to be sure a much wider group of users can edit something, such as a canonical answer to a very common question that might need to change over time. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, in fact, it's encouraged.